# Rigging an easy armature with bone constrains

Tags: rigging

[image: startposition]

[image: endposition]

i want to rig and set bone constrains, so that I only have to rotate the first bone around y, and the second bone moves with it but only on the x-axis (red) forwards and backwards. How to set those movement restrictions?

Comment: You could do the opposite, IK the forearm and move it, but maybe you only want to move upper arm for some reason? https://www.zupimages.net/up/23/49/ontx.gif

Comment: okay and how did you make this?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a good reason to move the lower arm instead of the upper arm, you could do the way around, i.e. move the lower arm to bend the whole arm: Create 3 bones, unparent bone 3, In *Pose* mode give an *IK* constraint to bone 2 with bone 3 as Target:

[image]

Result if you move bone 3 on X (you can even give a *Location* constraint to bone 3 so that it stays on this axis):

[image]

Comment: Okay thank you, but what if a want to rotate the first bone? How can i link the second joint to the x-axis and allow it to only move on the x-axis when i rotate the first bone around y??